# How can I disable my phone's magnetic field sensor or stop Android from using its data for `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`?

Tags: sensors, maps, orientation, compass, magnetometer

I've noticed that OsmAND's compass is much more accurate when forcing it to use the orientation sensor (`Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`) instead of the magnetic field sensor (`Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`).

Other (more modern) apps use `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` however and according to [the Android documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/sensors/sensor-types#rotation_vector), this combines data from the orientation sensors aswell as the magnetic field sensor.

How can I disable the magnetic field sensor entirely or prevent Android from using its data for `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`?

Comment: Have you tried to calibrate the magnetic sensor?

Comment: Yes I have. It's inaccurate in absolute terms and not even stable relatively. A 90° rotation does not amount to a 90° relative change. Context: https://lemmy.ml/post/2504120